# Degree of $f(x)=x^2$

Tags: differential-topology

Let $f:I\to I,$ where $I$ is compact set, given by $f(x)=x^2$

First, if $I$ is centered in $0$ then deg$(f)=0,$ cause $f$ isn't onto.
But, if we consider $f:I\to f(I),$ then $\operatorname{deg}(f)=2?$ Is true?

I thought this way: if $q\in f(I)$ is a regular value, then exist $p_{1}=\sqrt{q}$ and $p_{2}=-\sqrt{q}.$ Now, $\operatorname{sign}df(p_{1})=1$ and sign$ \ df(p_{2})=-1$, therefore $\operatorname{deg}(f)=0.$

Where is my mistake? I know that in complexes, the degree of $z^{m}$ is $m$.So it's natural to think that the degree of $x^2$ is $2.$

Other question, if $I=[a,b],$ if $a\geq 0,$ then $\operatorname{deg}(f)=1?$ If $b\leq 0,$ then $\operatorname{deg}(f)=-1?$

Comment: You didn't make a mistake. Assuming $I$ denotes an interval in $\mathbb{R}$, it's contractible, so the degree of any self-map is $0$, to the extent that this definition makes sense.

Comment: @hunter thank you sir, but what's the difference from what I did for the complex case?

Comment: You have to be very careful working with degree on non-compact manifolds or manifolds with boundary. The answer to your question, however, is that holomorphic maps are always orientation-preserving away from critical points. The same is not true of real smooth mappings.

Comment: @TedShifrin ooh, thank you sir!